# How to implement a C interface in Python and pass objects using CFFI

Tags: python, c, python-cffi, cffi

I would like to know how to use an existing C interface (a header file) and implement such an interface in Python by using the CFFI library.

For example, I have the following header file, `interface.h`:

```
void* foo(void* value);
```

And I want to implement it in Python. I thought the following program would do the work work, but it doesn't. It creates the function `foo`, but it doesn't guarantee that the implementation follows the structure defined in the header file.

```
import cffi

ffibuilder = cffi.FFI()

with open('interface.h') as f:
    data = ''.join([line for line in f if not line.startswith('#')])
    ffibuilder.embedding_api(data)

ffibuilder.set_source("_lib", r'''
    #include "interface.h"
''')

ffibuilder.embedding_init_code("""
    from _lib import ffi

     #include "interface.h"

    @ffi.def_extern()
    def foo(param):
        return __import__(param)

""")

ffibuilder.compile(verbose=True)
```

---

### How to pass Python objects using CFFI?

In the above example, as a result of calling `foo` that returns a Python object.
Then on the client-side, I have the following:

```
ffi = FFI()
# Load my lib file
lib = C.CDLL(dll)

h = lib.foo("math")
```

When I look up the value of h, it shows a number of type integer. However, I was expecting to receive an object. According to the interface, `foo` must return a pointer`void*`.  How can I read that object from it? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This looks correct to me.  What are you really asking?  Can you give an example of the kind of failure you're talking about?

Comment: For instance, if I change the implementation of the method `foo` to receive two arguments instead of one. It still works (I think it shouldn't because it doesn't match the specification of the header file).

Comment: "It still works" as in you can run the above script and compile the .so/.dll file, yes.  Just like you could compile it if the function contained a typo in a variable name.  It compiles but it fails at runtime.  If that's what you are concerned about then using Python in the first place is probably not the right choice...

Comment: you're right, @ArminRigo! thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your last question: you are using `ctypes`, not `cffi`, in this example.  These are different project.  It should be apparent because the `ffi` object is from `cffi`, but is unused in the following lines.  Instead of `lib = C.CDLL()` with I guess `C` being an alias to `ctypes`, you should call `lib = ffi.dlopen("...")`!

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was using `ctypes` for loading the DLL file. However, I tried changing it to `ffi.dlopen`, but it does not work when I try to call any function within the library. This is the output error:
  File "/python_app.py", line 65, in <module>
    print(py.foo(5))
  File "/python_app.py", line 51, in fooz
    return self.lib.foo(bn)
  File "/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cffi/api.py", line 912, in __getattr__
    make_accessor(name)
  File "/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cffi/api.py", line 907, in make_accessor
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: foo

Answer (score 1):

I found that the problem is that when switching from ctypes to CFFI for loading a DLL. The first requires the definition of the methods that are available in the dynamic library.
Therefore, adding this fixes the problem

```
ffi.cdef("""
  void foo(void* value);
""")
```